# Javascript function is not returning the value

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and taking a online class, I cant determine why this function does not return the intended value of 20.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script type = "text/javascript">
function calcpts(points)
{
    if (window.document.jsquiz.rad1[0].checked == true)
    {
        var pts = 0;
        pts = pts + parseint(20);
        alert(pay);
        return pay;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>JavaScript Quiz</h1>
<form name = "jsquiz">
    <p>Question #1 You can test a condition with an if..else statement or with  an if..elseif..else statement</p>
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad1" value="ques">True<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad1" value="ques">False<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="toClick" value="calculate" onclick="grossPts.value = calcpts(points)" >
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>Your total points are: <input type="text" name="grossPts" size="5" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your intention with `parseint(20)`? If you wan to use the number `20`, then just write `20`. `parseInt` is for extracting a number from a string.

Comment: Where the "pay" variable comes from??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error is on this line:

```
<input type="button" name="toClick" value="calculate"       onclick="grossPts.value 
= calcpts(points)" >
```

there is not a `points` variable declared so it throws an error, you need to calculate it or pass a number, you're not using the variable inside your function anyways.

The second error is that `parseint()` does not exist, change it for `parseInt()`

A third error is inside your function, your using a `pay` variable that does not exist, you need to declare the variables in order to be able to use them. But i guess you meant to write `pts` instead of `pay`

Here's a gift, because why not?:

```js
    function calcpts(points)
   {
    if (window.document.jsquiz.rad1[0].checked == true)
    {
    var pts = 0;
    pts = pts + parseInt(20);
    alert(pts);
    return pts;
    }
   }
```

```html
    <h1>JavaScript Quiz</h1>
   <form name = "jsquiz">
   <p>Question #1 You can test a condition with an if..else statement or with  an if..elseif..else statement</p>
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad1" value="ques">True<br>
    <input type = "radio" name = "rad1" value="ques">False<br><br>
    <input type="button" name="toClick" value="calculate"       onclick="grossPts.value 
= calcpts(0)" >
    </p>
    <br>
    <p>Your total points are: <input type="text" name="grossPts" size="5"    /></p>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace function `parseint` with `parseInt` in your code